# angulardart components - dispatch custom event

Tags: events, dart, angular-dart

I want to dispatch a custom event from my Angular Dart component to his parent. How can I do this with Angular Dart?

In other words I want do something similar to this: [How do you dispatch and listen for custom events in Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040193/how-do-you-dispatch-and-listen-for-custom-events-in-polymer)

Comment: Use `emit` (https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core.Scope@id_emit) and `on` (https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core.Scope@id_on) - you can find some code doing just that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151427/how-to-communicate-between-angular-dart-controllers (I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't _know_ Dart. But I know how it works and I know AngularJS, so I know about $emit and $on. I just googled the corresponding AngularDart methods of `Scope`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `emit` does what you want but I assume this works only within Angular.
If you want to send DOM events you can do it with `dispatchEvent` method like

```dart
Element e; // assigned by the injector through a constructor argument or aquired by querySelector, ...
...
var event = new CustomEvent(
  type, /* 'myeventname'
  canBubble: canBubble != null ? canBubble : true,
  cancelable: cancelable != null ? cancelable : true,
  detail: {'somekey', 'someValue'}
);
e.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can listen for this event by

```dart
e.on['myeventname'].listen((e) => print(e.details['somekey']));
```

or in Polymer (because I saw that you tried to make Angular work together with Polymer)

```dart
<some-element on-myeventname="{{myEventHandler}}"></some-element>
```

Comment: Currently I'm working on a Dart Angular only application. In this case do you thing is better to use the emit solution or the DOM event solution?

Comment: definitely `emit` or `broadcast`