# Polymer events from distant nodes

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to get familiar with polymer, and have been working my way through trying to build a sample application with it.  Following the tutorials at https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro and reading other StackOverflow questions such as [How do I fire a custom event from Polymer Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971511/how-do-i-fire-a-custom-event-from-polymer-dart) I have managed to build two elements where one element fires an event that is acted upon by the second element.  I have, however, only been able to figure out how to do this for cases where the firing element is a child of the listening element.  For example, as follows

**foo.html**

```dart
<link rel="import" href="bar.html">
<polymer-element name="foo">
    <template>
        <my-bar on-myevent="{{react}}"></mybar>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="foo.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**foo.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('my-foo')
class Foo extends PolymerElement {

  Foo() {}
  Foo.created() : super.created();

  void react() {
    print("Event happened and was heard!");
  }
}
```

**bar.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="bar">
    <template>
        <button on-click="{{click}}"></button>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="bar.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**bar.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('my-bar')
class Bar extends PolymerElement {

  Bar() {}
  Bar.created() : super.created();

  void click(Event e, var details, Node node) {
    print("Triggering event");
    fire('my-event');
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="foo.html">
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <foo></foo>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to move the `bar` button outside of the `foo` element, as in the app that I want to design, I would like the input controls to exist is a separate area of the page from the primary output display (the `foo` element).  Basically, I'd like to be able to make `foo.html` and `index.html` look like this:

**foo.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="foo">
    <template>
        <!-- Databound output stuff here -->
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="foo.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="foo.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bar.html">
</head>
<body>

<div id='control-panel'>
    <bar></bar>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <foo></foo>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find any examples on how, if I move the `bar` button out of the `foo` element, to get the event from `bar` to be visible to `foo`.  What would be the best way to listen to the event from `bar` when it is not a child of `foo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymer is designed around the idea of `controllers`. By this I mean, when A and B need to have some interaction, the preferred architecture is to create a third entity C. C can manage the lifecycle of A and B, and orchestrate communication. This kind of structure is excellent for maintainability, because users of C are insulated from the particulars of A and B, and A and B are insulated from everything. It also provides a convenient spot for impedance matching between A and B.

```
<polymer-element name="my-c">
 <template>
  <my-a on-my-event="{{coolAction}}"></my-a>
  ...
  <my-b id="b"></my-b>
 </template>
 <script>
   Polymer({
    coolAction: function() {
      this.$.b.doCoolThing();
    }
   });
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Users new to component structures often perceive this set-up as inconvenient, but my experience is that it's extraordinarily helpful once you get used to it.

Ultimately your view is a graph of components, where any particular sub-graph can generally be snipped off, replaced, or reattached with a minimum of stress. This is great for building flexible applications.

The `signals` concept exists for the rare occasion where you really want A and B to talk to each other directly, cutting across the component graph. This ability is almost never needed with a good application design, and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Since events bubble, the easiest way to handle this is to listen to a common ancestor of both elements.

Let's say you have this structure:

```html
<div id="event-bus">
  <my-a></my-a>
  <my-b></my-b>
</div>
```

Then `<my-b>` can listen for my-event on `#event-bus`.

To help ` find the event bus, you could set an attribute:

```html
<div id="event-bus">
  <my-a></my-a>
  <my-b event-bus="event-bus"></my-b>
</div>
```

```dart
class MyB extends PolymerElement {

  @published String eventBus;

  ready() {
    querySelector('#$eventBus').on['my-event'].listen((e){ react(); } );
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<polymer-signals>` element has been ported to Dart, which lets you fire a custom event anywhere, and listen to it anywhere.

Use it like `<polymer-signals on-polymer-signalfoo="{{foo}}"></polymer-signals>` where the event type you fire is `polymer-signal` and the data of the fire contains `{'name': 'foo', 'data': <your-data>}`

The port is here [polymer_elements for dart](https://github.com/bwu-dart/polymer_elements).

A good explanation of events in general for the javascript polymer which also describes how the `<polymer-signals>` works is described [communication and message passing](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html).