# Polymer, accessing custom elements / namespace issues

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype, polymer, web-component

I have been having some scope issues when developing a Polymer app.  Essentially I am attempting to use custom elements as classes containing pertinent logic.

Say I have a listener that is listening for a click event on a custom-elem element, and I want to access a function in another element, in this case the elements parent, parent:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-elem">
  <template>
  </template>
  <script>
     Polymer({
        attached: function(){
               this.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
                    if (e.which === 1){
                      this.parentNode.parentNode.testFunc(e);
                      //or this.parentNode.querySelector.... etc
                    }
                    else if (e.which === 3){
                    }


                }.bind(this));
}
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

I find I have to traverse the DOM to find the element I am looking for, or create a reference in a newly created element.  I realize I could create an object in an external script that contains logic above, but that seems to invalidate the purpose of defining custom elements / web components.

Is there anyway to easily access members of Polymer registered elements without navigating the DOM and without creating external scripts?

Comment: I'm thinking adding references on element creation to an object as the only solution to this problem.  Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have an easier time if you reconsider your approach to be more along the lines Polymer was designed for. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963632