# How do I create an`Event` instance with the `target` property set?

Tags: events, dom, dart

When I subscribe to the `onChange` event of an `InputElement`, the event type is `Event` and has the `target` property set:

```
new InputElement()
  ..onChange.listen((e) {
    print(e.runtimeType);
    print(e.target);
  });
```

How do I copy this behavior (for my own custom input box) and create events with the `target` property set?

None of the [`Event` constructors](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Event) allow you to pass a `target`, and the [`target` property](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Event#id_target) is get-only.

I tried finding the source for `InputElement` to see how it worked; but was unable to locate it in the Dart repo :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a CustomEvent instead.

```dart
dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('nameOfEvent'));
```

Just call `dispatchEvent` from the element you want to have set as `target`

```dart
  final someDiv = dom.querySelector('#some');
  someDiv.dispatchEvent(new dom.CustomEvent('xxx-yyy'));
```

In this question it is shown how to do it in Polymer elements [How do I fire a custom event from Polymer Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971511)

Comment: It's not really a custom event, it's a "change" event, which is an existing concept. I want my event to be as close to the textboxes own event as possible; as it's supposed to be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Should work the same with `Event` if you like it better.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by calling [`dispatchEvent`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.EventTarget#id_dispatchEvent) on the element, passing the `Event`:

```dart
var e = new Event.eventType('Event', 'change', canBubble: true, cancelable: false);
dispatchEvent(e);
```